# Why can you install the same package by different names with Yum

Tags: apache, centos, rpm, yum, centos6

On Centos 6 I can do

```
# yum install webserver
```

or

```
# yum install httpd
```

And both commands will install httpd (apache)

I am building an RPM and I don't know which one I should use or why they are different.
Do packages have a 'generic' name that you can address them by? For instance if you had lighttpd installed it could provide the webserver package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An RPM provides many things. Be they native library references, perl modules, etc. All are calculated while the RPM is built.

But you can also provide things yourself in a spec file (the file used to build an RPM), as in:

```
Provides: blablabla
```

So, it means the `httpd` package has:

```
Provides: webserver
```

in its spec file.

You can query what an installed package provides with:

```
rpm -q --provides pkgnamehere
```

But you can also ask what package provides something:

```
rpm -q --whatprovides theprovidedname
```

Finally, you can ask yum about provides:

```
yum whatprovides webserver
yum whatprovides grep
yum whatprovides /usr/bin/find
# etc etc
```